# See keywords that have changed position the most in Google Search Console when ones that didn't rank at all have a misleading average position of zero

Tags: google-search-console

In the Google Search Console, comparing the average position of same keywords shows the difference, as shown in the following examples:

[image]

The difference value is misleading because 0 (zero) means "query not listed", instead of "top position".
For example, the first query moved from not listed to 6.9 while the second moved from 59.5 to 70.7.

The difference is similar (7 and 11) but in reality the first had an amazing outcome (from nothing to 6.9), while the second just moved of 11 positions.

If this is correct, is there a better way to handle this data ?